# SQL getting top 2 rows by date per PolicyId but with distinct dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ValId | PolicyId | Date       | Value 
------+----------+------------+-------
    1 |   11     | 2020-06-01 | 2000
    2 |   11     | 2020-06-03 | 3000
    3 |   11     | 2020-06-03 | 4000
    4 |   12     | 2020-06-02 | 8000 
    5 |   12     | 2020-06-03 | 8500
```

I wanted to get top 2 latest `Val` rows for each `PolicyId` but they cannot be from the same date.

Rows for `PolicyId = 12` are returned correctly - ValId 4 and 5.

For `PolicyId = 11`, rows with ValId 2 and 3 are returned but as they are on the same date I wanted row of ValId 1 to be returned instead of ValId 2.

```
SELECT 
    V.ValId, V.PolicyId, V.Value, V.Date
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ValId, PolicyId, Value, Date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyId ORDER BY Date Desc, ValId DESC) AS RowNum
     FROM 
         TVal) V 
WHERE  
    RowNum <= 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate the rows by dates and within dates:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by policyid order by date desc valId desc) as seqnum,
             rank() over (partition by policyid, date order by valId desc) as seqnum_within_date
      from tval
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2 and seqnum_within_date = 1;
```

Comment: With 'seqnum <= 2'  in where clause, it will only return one row per PolicyId if the dates has duplicates

Comment: @Nanditha . . . I put the `dense_rank()` and `rank()` on the wrong expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion from [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) I was able to complete the sql as below

```
Select v.* from 
(
    select t.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by policyid order by date desc valId desc) as seqnum,
    from (select t.*             
          dense_rank() over (partition by policyid, date order by valId desc) as seqnum_within_date
          from tval
         ) t where seqnum_within_date = 1
)v where seqnum <= 2
```